# How to iterate subplots by columns instead of rows in matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop, matplotlib

Supposed I have a dataframe of 30 columns, with the first 10 columns being the 'mean' of various collected data, then the next 10 columns being 'median', and then the last 10 columns being 'mode'. For example, the 1st column is `height_mean`, the 10th column is `height_median`, and the 20th column is `height_mode`. The 2nd column is `weight_mean`, then 11th column is `weight_median`, and 21st column is `weight_median`.

| height_mean | ... | height_median | ... | height_mode | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 56 | ... | 58 | ... | 55 | ... |

I want to create a 10x3 subplot that takes the mean, median, and mode plots for each respective variable and plots them adjacently such that each row of the subplot is a new variable. So the first row of the subplots would have the mean, median, and mode plots for height, and the second row of the subplots would have the mean, median, and mode for weight, and so on.

So far, I have this, which creates the subplot in the order of the columns as they come in the dataframe:

```
fig, axs = plt.subplots(10, 3, figsize=(20,20))

for count, ax in zip(df.columns, axs.ravel()):
    df_data.loc[:,[count]].boxplot(ax=ax)
plt.show()
```

I tried to do something like this, but doesn't work:

```
for n, column in enumerate(df_columns):
    # add a new subplot iteratively
    ax = plt.subplot(10, 3, n + 1)
    df_data.iloc[:,[n]].boxplot(ax=ax)
    ax = plt.subplot(10, 3, n + 2)
    df_data.iloc[:,[n+9]].boxplot(ax=ax)
    ax=plt.subplot(10,3,n+3)
    df_data.iloc[:,[n+19]].boxplot(ax=ax)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To iterate the subplots column-wise, it's simplest to just transpose `axs` before raveling, i.e., `axs.T.ravel()`:

```
for col, ax in zip(df.columns, axs.T.ravel()):
```

Here is a minimal demo. Note how `weight_mean` now goes below `height_mean` rather than to the right:

```
headers = ['height_mean', 'weight_mean', 'height_median', 'weight_median', 'height_mode', 'weight_mode']
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((3, 6)), columns=headers)
#    height_mean  weight_mean  height_median  weight_median  height_mode  weight_mode
# 0     0.982351     0.548713       0.559040       0.497497     0.842977     0.738946
# 1     0.832716     0.660227       0.754149       0.286536     0.315156     0.312089
# 2     0.997460     0.290112       0.501917       0.974751     0.097419     0.559542

ncols = 3
nrows = len(df.columns) // ncols

fig, axs = plt.subplots(nrows, ncols, constrained_layout=True)
for col, ax in zip(df.columns, axs.T.ravel()):
    df[[col]].boxplot(ax=ax)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I didn't even think about doing a transpose. Much simpler and easier way if the data set is symmetric about some columns.